# Using Ubuntu Server in company (business related) / commercial use

Tags: server, license

From the [Ubuntu Intellectual property rights policy](https://ubuntu.com/legal/intellectual-property-policy):

*"Ubuntu is freely available to all users for personal, or in the case of organizations, internal use."*

What is considered as internal use by Ubuntu?

Applications will be deployed and accessed by internal employees as well as 3rd parties like suppliers and customers. We are planning to use Ubuntu LTS server here without support.
Thank you.

Comment: Why ask here?  That sounds like a question for Canonical (legal etc), rather than asking Ubuntu end-users.  Even if we do provide advice; it's only going to be a user opinion (*off-topic opinion which is against site rules*) as this is a end-user Q&A site.

Comment: @guiverc maybe some end-users already have asked Canonical legal department and got answer. I am not in position to ask Canonical legal department.

Comment: @karel yes, that's only way to read it and reason for asking here :-)

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but I was involved in analyzing open source software usage at my company and have some knowledge in that matter. "Internal use" usually means that you don't include the software into any product or service you are selling to your customers, but use it only for purposes related to doing business inside your company. Basically, you don't redistribute the software and/or bundle it with your product - that is internal use.

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be quoting the [Ubuntu Intellectual Property Rights Policy](https://ubuntu.com/legal/intellectual-property-policy) (without attribution, shame upon you).

And you seem to be misreading it to suggest that Intellectual Property Rights are somehow related to the [Terms and Conditions for Use of Ubuntu Software](https://ubuntu.com/legal/terms). They are completely different. Folks who do not understand the difference should consult a lawyer.

Ubuntu is free for your organization to use as much as it likes for internal and external use. What your organization cannot do (oversimplified) is claim to be the author/owner of Ubuntu, nor to use Ubuntu trademarks in your dealings with others.

Go ahead and run your servers and their applications...assuming the applications licenses so permit.

Comment: I apologize for not referring to the link you posted.  

I am not lawyer but have fair understanding of differences you are pointing out.  Asked lawyers and they asked back what is "internal use". I am living in EU or USA. I don't have access to lawyers with knowledge of IP, licensing' etc 

Al I am looking is link on Ubuntu website where is written something like this: 
"Ubuntu is free for your organization to use as much as it likes for internal and external use. "
Thank you for your reply.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/community/governance/mission

Comment: If your lawyer(s) are unfamiliar with how Open Source software licenses work (which is what their response suggests), then I gently opine that your organization may be employing the wrong lawyer(s) to effectively meet your business' need.

Comment: @user535733 not easy task in place where I live. And copyright is not something here that most people care about :-). Thank you.